# Is there a word for an inferior substitute?

Tags: single-word-requests, australian-english

I was wondering if there is a word in English to describe a person fulfilling another's role, albeit not as proficient.

Answer (score 4):

There is a phrase, **[a poor second](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/poor#poor_16)** that conveys some aspect of this concept

> a long way behind the winner in a race, competition etc.
>   *My horse came in a poor second*

Also consider **[the B-Team](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=B-Team)**

> A second-rate problem-solving team sent in because more qualified personnel (the "A-Team") are unavailable or unwilling to deal with a given problem. This is often because the A-Team sees said problem as being beneath them or unworthy of their talents.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider some of the following.
• *[understudy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/understudy#Noun)*, “a performer who understudies; a standby”. One sense of the [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/understudy#Verb)  *understudy* is “to study or know a role to such an extent as to be able to replace the normal performer when required”.  *Understudy* usually refers to a substitute less capable than the normal performer, but sometimes the understudy is quite capable.
• *[stand-in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stand-in#Noun)* (already mentioned in other answers) means “A person of similar size and shape to an actor that "stands-in" for the actor during the lengthy process of setting up a shot, who, unlike a double, does not appear in the film” and ordinarily is a person less talented than the actual performer.
• *[deputy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deputy#Noun)*, “One appointed as the substitute of another, and empowered to act for him, in his name or his behalf; a substitute in office...”
• *[substitute](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substitute#Noun)*, “A replacement or stand-in for something that achieves a similar result or purpose” and “A player who is available to replace another if the need arises, and who may or may not actually do so”
• *[ersatz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ersatz#Noun)*, (previously mentioned in comments) “Something made in imitation; an effigy or substitute”
• *[knockoff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/knockoff#English)*, “An imitation of something, particularly a well-known product, usually lower in quality and price than the original”
• *[wannabe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wannabe#Noun)*, “Someone who wishes to be or do something, but lacks the qualifications or talent; an overeager amateur; an aspirant”; also *[would be](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/would-be#Noun)*

Comment: +1 for understudy - implying competence but not the same level of skill as the person for whom they substitute.  You could make it derogatory but it isn't inherently.

Answer (score 2):

[*Surrogate*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surrogate).

Something less negatively sounding might perhaps be just *substitute*.

Comment: _Ersatz_. But only if you pronounce it as in German: /'ɛrzats/, to rhyme with English _rare pots_.

Comment: +1 @JohnLawler= but now you've got me curious, what other pronunciation is there?

Comment: Ersatz is the first thing that came to my mind too.

Comment: How is a surrogate an inferior substitute? If anything, in case of a surrogate mother, it is when the initial person for the role of the mother can't do it for biological or other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

A "Stand-in" may be applicable. 
"Stand-in" applies that the person is a temporary measure and thus they are not the ideal person for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the person a *second-stringer.* It's a term borrowed from athletics but people use it in non-athletic contexts. Second string refers to players who are used as alternates (for sports that use alternates). There's less of a negative connotation. They can be good players, but usually not as good as the first string.

Answer (score 0):

I like *backup* for a person and *generic* for a product.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

[**stopgap**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stopgap): someone or something that is intended to be used for a short time and then replaced by someone or something better

[**makeshift**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/makeshift): a usually crude and temporary expedient: substitute

[**quick-fix**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quick-fix): an expedient usually temporary or inadequate solution to a problem

[**fill-in**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fill+in?show=1&t=1402060504): someone who takes the place of another person who is away for a short time: someone who fills in for someone else

[**pinch hitter**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pinch+hitter): any substitute for anything, esp. in an emergency

[**body double**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/body+double): a movie actor that substitutes for a leading performer, especially in distance shots or scenes not involving the face, such as close-ups of a portion of the body